# Por que la web se visualiza mal?

Tags: css3

Tengo una web, llamada http://ogar.pw y se ve bien en Chrome y en Internet Explorer, pero en firefox, no.. ¿por qué puedo ocurrir esto?

Así es como se ve en Chrome e IE:

[image: Chrome e IE]

Y así se ve en Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Además, ¿existe algún programa que me muestre problemas de compatibilidad o algo? No sé qué está mal.

Comment: Sería ideal que movieras el código relevante a la pregunta en sí

Comment: Estaria bien y seria de mucha ayuda que pusieras tu codigo para ver.
Pero de igual manera, estaria bueno que usaras librerias si no los usas como jQuery para tener compatibilidad entre los navegadores, con respecto a javascript. Tambien puedes consultar esta pagina para ver los codigos que son compatibles con navegadores. [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) Tambien esta pagina Hay disponibles tablas de compatibilidad tanto de CSS, el DOM y test de elementos HTML5 [Compatibility overview](https://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se puede ver hasta sin poner el código en la pregunta: tienes un `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` que se aplica bien en Chrome e IE, pero que sin el prefijo `-moz-` no se va a ver bien en Firefox.

Dentro de tu código en particular tienes esto:

```
#helloDialog {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    zoom: 80%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
}
```

Como puedes ver, hay un estilo definido específicamente para `-moz-transform` que no es el `translate`  sino el `scale` y eso hace que se sobreescriba la transformación definida arriba y que no se aplique la translación del diálogo y se vea mal posicionado.

La solución es simple, se puede añadir múltiples transformaciones separadas por coma, así que añade el `translate(-50%, -50%)` al `-moz-transform` y problema resuelto:

```
#helloDialog {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    zoom: 80%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%), scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
}
```

Así es como lo veo yo después de cambiar ese estilo en el inspector de elementos de Firefox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]